# Change the size and angle of D3 geoCircle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

how can I change the size of 2 circles which are overlapping, to be for example at fixed 50px radius?

And another question is how can I rotate the yellow circle for example 30 degrees?

I create a fiddle with my current progress: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osp4mzoj/)

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    circle = d3.geoCircle()
    projection = d3.geoOrthographic()

    path = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection)

    moonBackground = svg.append("path")
      .attr("fill", "#2b281b")
      .attr("d", path(circle())),

    moon = svg.append("path")
      .attr("fill", "yellow")
      .attr("d", path(circle.center([140, 0])()));
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say rotate the circle?

Comment: @FrazerKirkman Sorry, I meant to rotate the illuminated part in yellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're trying to paint the Moon. Well, I believe `d3.geoCircle` is the wrong tool for the task. That being said, what you're doing is a kind of hack.

Anyway, this is my 2 cents:

You can set the radii of the circles using [circle.radius()](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#circle_radius):

> If radius is specified, sets the circle radius to the specified angle in degrees, and returns this circle generator.

But don't do this, because this will mess with your "shadow" effect when positioning the yellow path. Instead, use [projection.scale()](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#projection_scale) to reduce the size of the Moon.

To rotate the illuminated part of the Moon you can tweak the [center](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#circle_center) of the circle (not the correct way to do it but this whole code is a hack anyway!):

```
.attr("d", path(circle.center([140, -30])()));
```

Here is your Moon (I put some stars on the background, just because):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  circle = d3.geoCircle(),
  projection = d3.geoOrthographic().translate([150, 150]).scale(100);

path = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(projection),

  circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(100))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("cx", () => Math.random() * 300)
  .attr("cy", () => Math.random() * 300),

  moonBackground = svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "#2f2c1f")
  .attr("d", path(circle())),

  moon = svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "yellow")
  .attr("d", path(circle.center([140, -30])()));
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code example and explanation. But now you got me wondering what would be a proper "non-hacky" way of doing this?

Comment: Using regular SVG circles and paths.